# Redo and Undo for the text on Image using HTML5 and canvas

Tags: html

Any idea how to use redo and undo functionality in HTML5.
I have a task for redoing and undoing the text changes on the image for an app in fb.

thanks in advance,
Sai.

Answer (score 0):

If you are drawing the image and text to the canvas then I would follow the example shown at The Pointy End of the Stick blog; http://pointystickgames.com/blog/?p=62

If not then perhaps you could give us some more details of your current approach.

Comment: Post some of the link: link only answers are not encouraged.